# Android: strings.xml automatically shows standalone="no"

Tags: android, xml, formatting

I have a strange problem. In the strings.xml file of my project, the first line is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` But every time I close and open the file, the first line changes automatically to `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>` and this I guess is not allowing me to run the project on real phone (it runs on emulator). Though I remove standalone="no" and save the file, it appears again when I open the file.

What is the reason for this and how to overcome this?

Thank you for your time.

Cheers,

Madhu

Update: The problem was not with the strings.xml file. It was with the app which sends data to my Android app. I found that out now :-)

Answer (score 2):

The XML standalone element defines the existence of an externally-defined DTD.

A value of no indicates that this XML document is not standalone and depends on an externally-defined DTD.

A value of yes indicates that the XML document is self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

No, thats not related, it's a standard xml tag:

http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-rmd

telling an xml parser how the document should be parsed. It's not related to android at all. And you can ignore it. The reason for your app not running on a real phone has to be something else.

Comment: I ran the app on phone yesterday and it worked. Today, without any changes, I run the code again and it doesn't work. And the only change I could see was this in strings.xml. And the same change is happening in all my Android projects in Eclipse. All strings.xml are automatically changing to standalone="no". So I thought that could be the reason. I cannot think of any other reason at this moment.

Comment: Could you tell me why is the strings.xml file changing on its own? It was not happening before today. Strings.xml file of all Android projects in Eclipse are changing automatically now.

Comment: sounds to me like you updated your eclipse or some of its plugins and maybe that broke something else aside of adding this attribute.

Comment: This is happening only from today and I have not updated Eclipse in the past 3-4 weeks.

Comment: Update: The problem was not with the strings.xml file. It was with the app which sends data to my Android app. I found that out now :-)